SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'reports.'
So I am trying to open one of my blades that contain reported's data. But, it keeps me sending an error like that and this is the controller :
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\Report;

class ReportController extends Controller
{
    public function approve(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $report = Report::findOrFail($id);

        $data = $request->validate([
            'response_message' => 'required|string|max:1000',
        ]);

        $report->update([
            'status' => 'approved',
            'response_message' => $data['response_message'],
        ]);

        session()->flash('success', 'Laporan berhasil di-ACC dan pesan balasan telah dikirim.');
        return redirect()->back();
    }

    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $user = auth()->id();
        if ($user === null) {
            return redirect()->route('login')->with('error', 'User ID tidak ditemukan. Pastikan Anda sudah login.');
        }

        $data = $request->validate([
            'reason' => 'required|string|max:255',
            'description' => 'nullable|string',
            'reportable_id' => 'required|integer',
            'reportable_type' => 'required|string',
        ]);

        $data['user_id'] = auth()->id();
        Report::create($data);

        return response()->json(['success' => true]);
    }

    public function showReports()
    {
        $reports = Report::with('user')->latest()->get();
        return view('admins.adminnotifikasi', compact('reports'));
    }

    public function userShow()
    {
        $reports = Report::where('user_id', auth()->id())
            ->where('status', 'approved')
            ->get();
             
        return view('pages.utama.user.show', compact('reports'));
    }

    public function deleteReport($id)
    {
        $report = Report::findOrFail($id);

        if (auth()->user()->role !== 'admin' && $report->user_id !== auth()->id()) {
            return redirect()->back()->with('error', 'Anda tidak memiliki izin untuk menghapus laporan ini.');
        }

        $report->delete();
        session()->flash('success', 'Laporan berhasil dihapus.');
        return redirect()->back();
    }
}

this is the model :
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class Report extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $table = 'reports';
    protected $fillable = [
        'reason',
        'description',
        'user_id',
        'status',
        'response_message',
        'reportable_id',
        'reportable_type',
    ];

    protected static function booted()
    {
        static::creating(fn($report) => $report->user_id = Auth::id());
    }

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'user_id'); // pastikan 'user_id' adalah foreign key yang benar
    }

    public function reportable()
    {
        return $this->morphTo();
    }
}

and below is the model that I reported
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\MorphMany;

class AdaApa extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $table = 'adaapa';
    protected $fillable = ['title', 'content', 'image'];

    public function comments(): MorphMany
    {
        return $this->morphMany(Comment::class, 'commentable');
    }

    public function likes(): MorphMany
    {
        return $this->morphMany(Like::class, 'likeable');
    }

    public function reports(): MorphMany
    {
        return $this->morphMany(Report::class, 'reportable');
    }
}

user model :
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use App\Http\Controllers\DiscussionsController;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use HasFactory, Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array<int, string>
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'username', // Tambahkan username di sini
        'email',
        'password',
        'role',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for serialization.
     *
     * @var array<int, string>
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password',
        'remember_token',
    ];

    /**
     * Get the attributes that should be cast.
     *
     * @return array<string, string>
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
        'password' => 'hashed',
    ];

    public function discussions()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Discussions::class);
    }

    /**
     * Relasi ke model Report.
     */
    public function reports()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Report::class);
    }

    
}

And there is nothing wrong with my database, I send it succesfult to my database here. So there is nothing wrong also with my route, but I have no idea why it keeps said an error like. Also this is my blade that I use to show the data :
@foreach ($reports as $report)
        <div class="alert alert-info">
            <strong>Nama User:</strong> {{ $report->user->name ?? 'Tidak diketahui' }}<br>
            <strong>Berita yang Di-Report:</strong> {{ $report->reportable->title ?? 'Tidak diketahui' }}<br>
            <strong>Alasan:</strong> {{ $report->reason }}<br>
            <strong>Alasan:</strong> {{ $report->status }}<br>
            <strong>Deskripsi:</strong> {{ $report->description ?? 'Tidak ada deskripsi' }}<br>
            <small>Dilaporkan pada: {{ $report->created_at }}</small>

            <!-- Form untuk ACC dan mengirim pesan balasan ke user -->
            <form action="{{ route('report.approve', $report->id) }}" method="POST" class="mt-3">
                @csrf
                <div class="mb-2">
                    <label for="responseMessage">Pesan Balasan:</label>
                    <textarea name="response_message" class="form-control" rows="2" placeholder="Masukkan pesan balasan untuk user..."></textarea>
                </div>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Approve Report</button>
            </form>
            <form action="{{ route('report.delete', $report->id) }}" method="POST" class="mt-2" onsubmit="return confirm('Apakah Anda yakin ingin menghapus laporan ini?');">
                @csrf
                @method('DELETE')
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Delete Report</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    @endforeach


It seems that function reports should be belongsTo with report id instead of morphMany.

It looks like the error is due to an issue with the polymorphic relationship setup. Check reportable_type and reportable_id, make sure reportable_type in reports has the correct model name App\Models\AdaApa, and reportable_id references the right record. Update Relationship in AdaApa below.
public function reports(): MorphMany
{
    return $this->morphMany(Report::class, 'reportable');
}

In the blade template, also confirm that {{ $report->reportable->title }} is referencing data correctly.
